# Fixed nav scrolls ahead (misplaced menu)

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, nav

I just customized my fixed nav on my web and it works but for one thing - every header type of page doesn't recognize the main menu as **under the header**. When I load every page for the first time, the menu itself appears at the top of the page and it's like the fixed nav is taking the main nav up with it instead of not appearing at all until reaching the actual menu (the header is about 305px high).

I'm not sure if there's something wrong with the elements' order or if it's because of the js offset. But before adding the fixed nav everything worked just fine and every page loaded the menu under the header.

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>

<body class='header-page page-has-banner  wsite-theme-dark'>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="banner-wrap">

      <div class="container">
        <div class="banner">{content}</div>
      </div>

</div><!-- end banner-wrap -->


  <div class="dusk-header">
  <div class="nav-wrap">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo">{logo}</div>
      <div class="nav desktop-nav"></div>

      <label class="hamburger"><span></span></label>

    </div><!-- end container -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main-wrap">
  {{#sections}}
    <div class="container">{content}</div>
  {{/sections}}
</div><!-- end main-wrap -->

<div class="footer-wrap">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="footer">{footer}</div>
  </div><!-- end container -->
</div><!-- end footer-wrap -->
</div>

<div class="nav mobile-nav">{menu}</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/files/theme/plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/files/theme/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
/* Fixed Nav */
 body.page-has-banner.affix {
 padding-top: 65px;
 }

 body.page-has-banner.affix .dusk-header {
 position: fixed !important;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 15;
 }

/* Fade out scroll */
 body.fade-on-scroll .banner {
 opacity: 0;
 }
/* Mobile app */
 body.wsite-checkout-page .dusk-header,
 body.wsite-native-mobile-editor .dusk-header {
 position: absolute !important;
 }
/* Header */
 .dusk-header {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 10;
 width: 100%;
 background: @navBg;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
 -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
 -ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
 -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
 transition: all 300ms ease;
 }
.dusk-header .nav-wrap {
 width: 100%;
 background: @navBg;
 -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
 -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
 -ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
 -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
 transition: all 300ms ease;
 }
.dusk-header .container {
 display: table;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 }
.dusk-header label.hamburger {
 display: none;
 }
.dusk-header .logo {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-right: 30px;
 color: white;
 }
.dusk-header .logo .wsite-logo {
 vertical-align: auto !important;
 }
.dusk-header .logo a {
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-right: 30px;
 color: white;
 letter-spacing: 0.03em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-size: 26px;
 font-weight: 300;
 line-height: 40px;
 }
.dusk-header .logo img {
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 max-width: 200px;
 max-height: 40px;
 }
.dusk-header .logo #wsite-title {
 display: block;
 max-width: 400px;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-size: 26px;
 font-weight: 300;
 line-height: 40px;
 }
```

after that follows the nav code

**js**

```
// Fixed nav
$.fn.checkElementPositioning = function($el, $offsetHeightEl, scrollClass) {
if (!this.length) {
  return;
}

    if(((this.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) <= 
$offsetHeightEl.outerHeight()) && !$el.hasClass(scrollClass)) {
        $el.addClass(scrollClass);
    } else if(((this.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) >= 
$offsetHeightEl.outerHeight()) && $el.hasClass(scrollClass)) {
        $el.removeClass(scrollClass);
    }
}
```

Any ideas or do I needs to provide more info?